# Failed login attempts, constant brute force

Tags: ssh, debian, firewall, iptables, internet-security

I'm running a VPS with an iptables firewall (configured via ufw). I have shut down all traffic with:

```
sudo ufw default deny incoming
sudo ufw default allow outgoing
```

After that I have opened certain ports for ssh and other services I need.
This morning I checked `/var/log/auth.log` and realized I'm being brute forced continually

```
Failed password for root from <IP> port 36202 ssh2
... 
Invalid user admin from <IP> port 57267
```

A lot of above messages are listed, in the hundreds.

I've disabled the login for root after that (should have done it earlier); `ufw status` says firewall is active; `netstat -tulpn ssh` lists only the ports I know are enabled.

Why am I getting this in the logs? Does this mean that the attacker is able to connect via ssh and subsequently gets denied access on account of bad password? I also have rsa keys authentication setup. What other steps should I take?

Comment: If you don't get an answer hear, try https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: is the IP address always the same? if so, consider Fail2Ban https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail2ban it can be configured to block the IP address in your firewall if the IP has a number of failed login attempts.

Comment: No, it's always a different IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are being attacked. The reason is likely because you have port-forwarded
the standard SSH ports on your router. In this way you have signaled
the hackers of the entire world that here is an SSH server waiting
to be attacked using dictionaries of standard user-names and
often-used passwords.

I suggest that you port-forward some other port from the router,
for example router port `2222` forwarded to `22`, and close port `22`
on the router.

You should examine carefully all open ports on the router
([GRC ShieldsUP!](https://www.grc.com/x/ne.dll?bh0bkyd2)
is a good tester).

As you are under brute-force attack, don't use trivial passwords or
standard user names.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but this doesn't answer my questions. I will check out GRC ShieldsUP!, though.

Comment: I think it answers the questions, or at least as I understood them. Could you explain?

Comment: Sorry, but it just clicked. The ports that are logged in the messages provided in my question aren't ports on my machine, but ports on the attacker's, correct? Also, I've set ssh to listen on a different port now and the messages stopped. What can I say, I'm a noob.
Thank you, you actually did answer my questions :)